# On Logarithmic Properties Applied to the Logistic Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I wondered if anyone could help direct me through the steps of (1) through to (2) please?

Below **(1)** is presented as logistic equation:

$$P = \frac{1}{1+e^{-(B_1X + B_0 + u)}}$$ 
where $u$ is an error term of the logistic regression, $B$'s are the parameters, and X$ $the independent variable.

What I am asking is that, how does it go to (2) by taking logs?

Where **(2)** is:

$$\ln \frac{P}{1-P} = B_1X + B_0 + u$$

Your help would be appreciated,

Best,

Andrew

Comment: Yeah, that's the one. In the text it has parantheses however. Albeit I am willing to accept that the use of such could be mistaken.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated for future input.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity I'm just going to say $x = B1X + B0 + u$:

$P = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$

$1-P = 1-\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} = \frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}$

$\frac{P}{1-P} = \frac{1+e^{-x}}{e^{-x}(1+e^{-x})} = e^x$

then you're there!

Comment: Thank you battlewink. And thank you also for your contribution N.F. Taussig. I understand your steps once I see them written down. May I ask where the '1-' comes from in your second step battlewink?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I'm just building up an equation. I want to express P/(1-P) as simply as possible so I just write P simply then 1-P simply; it's just a personal preference in explaining steps.

Answer (score 0):

$$P = \frac{1}{1+e^{-(B_1X + B_0 + u)}}$$

$$ \frac{1}{P} = 1 + e^{-(B_1X + B_0 + u)} $$

$$ \frac{1}{P} - 1 = \frac{1-P}{P} = e^{-(B_1X + B_0 + u)} $$

$$  \ln \left( \frac{1-P}{P} \right) = -(B_1X + B_0 + u)$$

$$  -\ln \left( \frac{1-P}{P} \right) = B_1X + B_0 + u$$

$$ \ln \frac{P}{1-P} = B_1X + B_0 + u  $$

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your help there.